# How to ignore a key in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

How can I not care about `p1` or `p2`?

I will never care whether a player is player1 or player2, per se.
All I care about is that they played against each other in a match.

I have documents in this format, it represents one game of a match in a tournament:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('5490690b2e8738094b2f8753'),
 u'date': u'2014-08-02',
 u'game': 7,
 u'players': {u'p1': {u'char': u'marth',
                      u'name': u'jack',
                      u'stocks': {u'stock1': {u'dmg': 133, u'time': 89},
                                  u'stock2': {u'dmg': False,
                                              u'time': False},
                                  u'stock3': {u'dmg': False,
                                              u'time': False},
                                  u'stock4': {u'dmg': False,
                                              u'time': False}}},
              u'p2': {u'char': u'fox',
                      u'name': u'ben',
                      u'stocks': {u'stock1': {u'dmg': 45, u'time': 15},
                                  u'stock2': {u'dmg': 77, u'time': 35},
                                  u'stock3': {u'dmg': 102, u'time': 78},
                                  u'stock4': {u'dmg': 80, u'time': 120}}}},
 u'stage': u'bf',
 u'tournament': u'King of Kings 2014'}
```

I want to find all games that involve the player with `name` '`ben`'; it is irrelevant if he is `p1` or `p2`.
I only know that I can do this:

```
db.games.aggregate([{'$project' : {'players.p1.name': 1}},
    {'$group': {'_id' : '$players.p1.name', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}])
```

**Output:**

```
{u'ok': 1.0,
 u'result': [{u'_id': u'ben', u'count': 4},
             {u'_id': u'man', u'count': 21},
             {u'_id': u'hammy', u'count': 5},
             {u'_id': u'left', u'count': 9},
             {u'_id': u'armed', u'count': 12},
             {u'_id': u'icicle', u'count': 11},
             {u'_id': u'2king', u'count': 45},
             {u'_id': u'strangelove', u'count': 9},
             {u'_id': u'jack', u'count': 16}]}
```

But it only gives me `p1`. As I said earlier, I don't actually care what player number they are.

Can you please advise me on if I should change my data structure (schema?), so that I can easily perform these kinds of lookups efficiently.

I tried putting the players into a `players` array (without `p1`/`p2` keys, but that seemed to make other queries harder).

So I am not sure what is the best strategy in this case...

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is add the players in an array.

```
{
    "_id" : ...
    ...
    "ps" : ["jack", "ben"]
    ...
}
```

To find all matches that jack played in,

```
db.games.find({ "ps" : "jack" })
```

It seems to me you'd have a more natural structure if each player were an object in a length 2 array, and you'd be able to do a query similar to the above to find all matches involving a given player, but you said that makes other queries more difficult. You didn't say what queries those are, so I can't help you with them, but adding in an extra array with just the names should help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the structure of your document, how about something like this using Python's MongoDB API?

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()
document = db.my.collection.find({},{"_id":0})

names = []

for document in documents:
    for players in document['players']:
       names.append(document['players'][players]['name'])

for name in set(names):
   print "{0}:{1}".format(name, names.count(name))
```

Instead of "print" you can assign the result to a list or dictionary.